# Terminologia - Qual a diferença entre instrução e declaração?

Tags: python, terminologia

Qual seria a diferença delas?

Instrução seria uma linha de código que representa certos comandos/ações passadas para o computador executar.

Declaração, seguindo a lógica, seria um tipo de instrução? Já que, pelo que entendi, seria uma instrução para declarar algo (uma instrução de declaração de variável, por exemplo).

Existe alguma diferença entre essas duas palavras?

Agradeço a todos!

Comment: Você está interessado apenas em respostas restritas a Python especificamente ou você quer algo mais amplo que aborde como instruções e declarações são tratadas na maioria das linguagens de programação (que as tratam de forma bem similar)? De qualquer forma, a minha resposta deve abordar ambos os casos.

Comment: Você sabe dizer em inglês o significado dessas palavras? Porque eu acho que está falando de *statement* e não *declaration*, o que dá uma resposta completamente diferente. No Brasil traduzimos mal esses termos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaração é quando você declara uma variável, função, método, classe ou coisa semelhante.

Instrução é aquilo onde você instrui ao programa executar uma determinada ação.

Declarações normalmente não são consideradas instruções porque elas dizem algo que explica para o compilador ou interpretador onde é que determinados dados são gravados ou qual é o formato deles. Não trata-se normalmente de algo a ser diretamente executado e que vá surtir algum tipo de efeito em algum lugar.

Já as instruções são coisas a serem executados em determinados momentos e que surtem algum tipo de efeito: alteram valores de variáveis, alocam ou (dependendo da linguagem) desalocam memória, modificam o estado da pilha de execução, realiza algum tipo de entrada ou saída, etc. Declarações não fazem isso, pois não são executáveis, elas apenas dão nomes à algumas coisas.

É verdade que você pode ter alguma coisa assim, dependendo da linguagem de programação:

```js
var x = 123;
```

Nesse caso, a declaração é o `var x` e a inicialização é o `x = 123`. A inicialização é um tipo de atribuição que é um tipo de instrução. No caso, essa linha contém uma declaração e uma instrução. Elas poderiam ser separadas com esse equivalente:

```js
var x;
x = 123;
```

No Python especificamente, o uso de `class MinhaClasse:` é uma declaração de classe, enquanto que `def meu_metodo():` é uma declaração de método. O Python não exige a declaração de variáveis em outros casos, mas esses são exigidos em outras linguagens de programação, em especial aquelas que têm tipagem estática, tais como C, C++, Java, C#, Pascal, Delphi, Rust entre muitas outras.

Comment: Agradeço demais a ajuda e o tempo disposto.
Agora compreendi bem as 2 formas. Elas não estavam muito bem explicadas em minha mente, mas agora deu pra entender bem. Agradeço Victor!

Answer (score 0):

> A pergunta tem `Python` como tag, mas a terminologia é, em geral,
>   aplicável a todas as linguagens de programação.

**Instrução:** solicitar fazer algo ou dizer o modo de fazer.

**Declaração:** passar, alterar ou criar uma informação.

A segunda pode estar contida na primeira, já que declarar algo não deixa de ser uma instrução, embora não cause nenhuma ação imediata.

Ao escrever `x = true` estou declarando ao programa que agora a variável `x` é verdadeira, e também estou instruindo o programa a tratar essa variável desta forma.

Por outro lado, uma instrução, propriamente dita, é como uma "ordem" que o código manda o programa fazer algo, ou seja, executar uma ação ou uma condição, na maioria das vezes, conforme as declarações que foram feitas.

Um exemplo simples seria:

```
x = 1; // declaração
alert(x+10); // instrução
```

Um outro exemplo de instrução seria:

```
if x == 1 then x = x+10
```

Estou instruindo o programa que, se `x` for igual a `1`, ele deve ser incrementado com mais `10` no seu valor.

A diferença entre um termo e outro é que um é passivo, apenas declara informações, enquanto o outro executa essas informações ou ações dentro do programa.