# Qual a diferença entre comando, instrução e código?

Tags: terminologia

- Qual a diferença entre eles no contexto de programação?
- Posso usar esses termos de forma intercambiável?
- Caso eles sejam diferentes, qual é o termo correto para definir o que escrevemos?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261818/8063

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As pessoas os usam de forma intercambiável em muitos casos, mas não deveriam porque os significados precisos não são a mesma coisa, e é até difícil defini-los claramente, pelo menos em português.

Óbvio que o importante na maior parte do tempo é ser compreendido, se não tiver ambiguidade pode usar.

**Código** deveria ser algo amplo, mas tem muita gente que usa como se fosse algo específico, chama de código algo menor, algo que é um trecho, algo que pode ser uma instrução ou comando, mas ele só deveria ser usado formalmente para o todo.

Estritamente falando **instrução** só é usado em código baixo nível e se refere ao menor comando possível que o processador pode executar, é uma operação simples que ele consegue fazer, tal como fazer uma operação aritmética ou relacional, transportar dado nos registradores ou memória ou controlar o fluxo de execução do código.

Mas há algum uso informal quando se trata de linguagens de alto nível. Se usado corretamente o termo instrução deveria ser para algo mínimo, uma operação simples que a linguagem ou biblioteca manda executar, mesmo que ali já tenha uma grande abstração. Algumas pessoas usam como sinônimo exato para comando.

O **comando** é um meio termo, ele nem é algo mais complexo, ele determina algo maior a ser executado, embora possa eventualmente ser uma instrução simples, mas só porque tudo o que o comando quer fazer é simples mesmo, mas não é o todo.

O termo é um pouco controverso e na verdade usamos ele para traduzir *statement* que na verdade é só uma declaração, mas não só uma declaração de variável ou função, é a declaração de intenção do que quer que o computador execute.

Se estiver falando neste contexto seria isto, em outros contextos pode nem ter a ver com o código e sim com arquitetura ou engenharia geral.

A pergunta *linkada* no comentário acima tem resposta usando declaração como *declaration* mesmo, o que eu acho que sequer era a intenção da pergunta, mas enfim. Eu estou usando declaração como *statement*.

E justamente por criar essa confusão é comum preferirmos chamar de comando (que em inglês deveria ser *command*). Eu falei que era confuso logo no começo :)

```
if (x == 1 && y > 0) return;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Statement.ptg).

Aí tem um (trecho de) **código**, que é um **comando**, composto por **instruções** (`if`, `x == 1`, `y > 0`, a condição composta por estas 2 relacionadas com `&&` e o `return`). Como em alto nível não se costuma usar instrução, alguns podem entender um pouco diferente e pode até falar informalmente que este código todo seja uma instrução.

Então o comando pode ser considerado tudo o que está em uma linha (mesmo que tenha quebra visual de linha, mas ainda é uma linha no sentido de execução).

Lembrando que estou usando os termos muito informalmente, mas que foi popularizado assim.

Answer (score 3):

Segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_de_m%C3%A1quina):

> Um programa em código de máquina consiste de uma sequência de bytes que correspondem a instruções a serem executadas pelo processador. [...] Uma instrução em código de máquina consiste em uma sequência de bytes, onde cada byte significa algo para o processador.

Entende-se, por isso, que um código é um conjunto de instruções. Novamente, segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instru%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(inform%C3%A1tica)):

> Em ciência da computação, uma instrução é uma operação única executada por um processador e definida por um conjunto de instruções. Num sentido amplo, uma "instrução" pode ser qualquer representação de um elemento num programa executável, tal como um bytecode.

E segundo a [Anhanguera de Niterói](https://sites.google.com/site/unipliarquitetdecomputadores/aulas/aula-1---estrutura-da-cpu---conjunto-de-instrucoes):

> Uma instrução de máquina  é a formalização de uma instrução primitiva que a máquina pode realizar diretamente.

Uma instrução é a menor ação que pode ser feita em um computador usando programação. Corresponderia a uma ação a baixo nível, como uma instrução em Assembly, ou mesmo uma instrução binária escrita em linguagem de máquina.

Ainda, segundo a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comando_(inform%C3%A1tica)):

> Comando em informática é a representação atômica e elementar de uma ação do computador, podendo ser invocada por usuário, sistemas aplicativos ou programas.

Embora seja usada no contexto cotidiano como uma função ou operação (ex: [`goto`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), [`do...while`](https://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/LaproI/ComandosDeRepeticao/Repeticao.html), etc), o conceito mais "correto" de um comando, segundo o meu entendimento, é parecido com o de instrução: um comando único, indivisível. A menor coisa que pode ser feita em um programa.

Relacionado:

- [Qual a diferença entre instrução e declaração?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/261818/terminologia-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-instru%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o);
- [Instruções, expressões e operadores (Guia de Programação em C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/);
- [Aula 2 - Estrutura da CPU - Conjunto de Instruções](https://sites.google.com/site/unipliarquitetdecomputadores/aulas/aula-1---estrutura-da-cpu---conjunto-de-instrucoes)